# Bump Node Not Going Through When Connected Into Normals

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm connecting the bump Node into the normals of the principle BSDF shader , but it's not appearing on my texture. A user already helped me set up the nodes. But I'd like to add a bump to it as well.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Connect the noise output to the height input of the bump node

Comment: I connected the noise output to the height of the bump node, but now I'm getting a non transparency. The PNG file has a background to it. https://ibb.co/QHtTC7P

Comment: Plug the alpha output of the Image texture node into the alpha of the principled bsdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, when I posted an image before, I forgot to connect the bump node. It really shouldn't change that much though, The only thing I can think is the subsurface color is interfering. I'll post the setup once again (without subsurface color) to show the setup that works for me. You can add subsurface after and see if that's the problem (if you also used 2 materials, maybe you added it to one and not the other). Once again, I used 2 materials, one for the block, and one for the wolf face. This can be done all in one, but, first things first. Have a look:

[image: Wolf1]

[image: Wolf2]

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Connect a texture to the bump. Either a normal map into the normal input or a texture (such as noise) into the height input. Then control the strength with the distance and the strength values.

[image]